# How to group by 3 columns in pandas and calculate its frequency per year starting from the first entry given in date column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe where there are 4 columns

I want to group by x,y,z columns and get the count of these combinations which lie in same year starting from the first entry in that grouped frame.

I have :

```
x y z date
1 2 2 08-12-2016 00:00
1 3 2 24-03-2017 00:00
1 2 2 22-04-2017 00:00
1 2 2 22-04-2019 00:00
```

I want :

```
x y z  level count
1 2 2  1        2
1 3 2  1        1
1 2 2  2        1
```

the Bin represents the Bin number in which these combinations have fallen and count represents the count of these combinations in that particular bin

thank you

Comment: Can you explain you expected output more? You want to "get the count of these combinations which lie in same year" but no groups of `['x', 'y', 'z']` share the same year.

Comment: Hello Chris , the first date of combination (1,2,2) is 08-12-2016 00:00 so one year bin results to 08-12-2016 00:00 + 1 year = 08-12-2017 00:00,so count of same combinations (1,2,2) within this bin is 2 ,I want this count

Comment: So not falling in the same year but within one calendar year of each other?

Comment: Yes exactly i wanted the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this...using `resample`

```
# sample df
s = """x,y,z,date
1,2,2,08-12-2016 00:00
1,3,2,24-03-2017 00:00
1,2,2,22-04-2017 00:00
1,2,2,22-04-2019 00:00"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# create a count column
df['count'] = 1
# groupby [x,y,z], resample your date by 365 days and count
df2 = df.groupby(['x', 'y', 'z']).apply(lambda g: g.set_index('date').resample('365D')[['count']].count())
# boolean indexing to get rid of zeros
final = df2[df2['count'] != 0]

                  count
x y z date             
1 2 2 2016-08-12      2
      2018-08-12      1
  3 2 2017-03-24      1
```